# What are the sections for local system in Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For example, one can consider the local system on $\mathbb{P}^1-\{0,\infty\}$, with monodromy $
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$. This defines a sheaf (one may need to further restrict that the coefficients are $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. stalks at any point is $\mathbb{Q}^2$). So my question is, how did sections defined?

In Zariski topology, all opens sets are like $\mathbb{P}^1-\{0,\infty,p_1,...,p_n\}$ or empty. And in my intuition, any nontrivial open set conatins a non trivial cycle around $0$, thus sections are subspaces of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ that invariant under monodromy so must be $\mathbb{Q}$. So where did $\mathbb{Q}^2$ comes from?

Comment: Local systems are (almost) never considered for the Zariski topology. If you work over $\bf C$, then you have to use the ordinary topology. If you work over other fields, you have to use the étale topology and replace $\bf Q$ by ${\bf Q}_\ell$.